# Reformatting partition to ntfs

Tags: partitioning

I am trying to install windows 8 on my PC that is currently running Ubuntu. I have tried to reformat the partition to ntfs however I can out unmount it because it is in use. I have tried using gparted but that does not seem to work. How can I reformat the partition? My data is already backed up on an external hard drive.

Comment: Please provide more detail, like how many partitions you have, which partition you wan to format, better a screenshot of Gparted`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: "How can I reformat the partition?" Guess what the 1st thing the windows installer is going to do when you try to install windows.

Comment: When I try to install windows it says that it needs a partition in ntfs format. So it won't do it for me

Answer (score 0):

You should use gparted from a live-cd/usb.

For example with the image.iso of Gparted:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gparted/gparted-live-0.19.1-4-i486.iso

The bootable GParted Live image can also be installed on a Cd/Usb flash drive.

After you download the imagen.iso, run the Unetbootin program and follow the instructions in the GUI to install GParted Live on your USB flash drive.

or

From a terminal, run the following command using the gparted .iso file name and Cd/Usb device path:

```
$ sudo -i
# dd if=/path-to-gparted-live.iso of=/dev/sdx bs=4M; sync
```

Note: replace x by their corresponding drive (b-c-d-e)